# Does Azure function 2.0 support System.Drawing?

Tags: azure-function-app

We tried to create thumbnail from PDF in somewhere around Jan 2020 and deployed Azure Functions (v2 using .NET Core) but we have faced error that "System.Drawing is not supported on this platform".

But from last week the same code in Azure Functions (v2 using .NET Core) is working fine and return no error.

So want to know if there Microsoft provides any release to support System.Drawing in Azure Function 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

System.Drawing is not supported on the Azure Functions Consumption plan.
If you need to use System.Drawing, then you need to use an App Service Plan that is not based on the consumption plan.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions v3 now supports System.Drawing with a Windows app service.